# Batch script issue with the current directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have used a batch file in which i am setting absolute path variable as below

**Code snippet(Batch File : brk_validation.bat)**

```
SET ABS_PATH=%~dp0

echo  Completed the Validation of files in %ABS_PATH%
```

**Running the Batch Program on command prompt:**

```
D:\Files>brk_validation.bat .
```

**Output :**

```
Completed the Validation of files in D:\Files\
```

**Issue:**

I have put the batch file in a different directory and then running the bat file by giving the full path of it as shown below:

```
 D:\Files>D:\Work\brk_validation.bat .
```

**Output :**

```
Completed the Validation of files in D:\Work\
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Completed the Validation of files in D:\Files\
```

I want the current directory path where the files are present i.e. D:\Files for the above example.

So any help is appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current directory;

```
SET ABS_PATH=%cd%
```

Comment: Sorry i am able to get now...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be `SET ABS_PATH=%~dp1` The `%0` variable is the filename of the batch file itself.

Comment: This particular value set in ABS_PATH is not working to get the full path of the current directory.